# How to manage multiple node projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

We are using 3 different **node** projects: *Project 1*, *Project 2* and *Project 3* using **react** and **webpack**. All 3 projects are hosted in 3 different repositories.

*Project 1* and *Project 2* are independent but *Project 3* needs zip file of both *Project 1* and *Project 2* and are put in *Project 3* as devDependencies(node_modules).

Now the problem comes when we need to make changes in *Project 1* or *Project 2* so that the new zip file can be used in *Project 3*.

For debugging, we need to change the code in *Project 1* or *Project 2* and then build a zip using `npm pack` and then update that zip in *Project 3* and stop the build of *Project 3* and then uninstall and install that zip again and then run the *Project 3* again.

The other, a little bit faster, a solution is to build *Project 1* or *Project 2* using npm pack and then copy the lib file generated and then copy that in `/node_modules/Project 1(or2)/lib` folder in *Project 3* running instance.

Is there a better or faster or more convenient way to do manage all these projects?

Please don't suggest [lerna](https://lernajs.io/). Lerna is a great tool but it needs change in architecture which is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put them all in one repo. Then you are guaranteed to know where all the projects are relative to each other. Each project is just a sub-folder, and has it's own `package.json` as it does now.

You just need some scripts that will do the zipping and copying to the right place in each project.

I would make those scripts run from the top level of the project (which has it's own `package.json`, in the scripts folder. Some adjustments of `.gitignore` to stop zip files getting checked in and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have done to solve my multi repo problem. All my projects are in different repos but I have downloaded those multiple repo projects inside a single parent folder. I use VS Code so I simply open the parent folder in VS Code and then have written a few scripts to do uninstall, install and copy paste process via tasks.json in .vscode folder at the parent level.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you publish project1 and project2 to npm?

```
npm publish project1
npm publish project2
```

Makes these projects devDependencies in project3.

Then just an `npm install` in project3 will get the lastest project1 and project2.

If privacy is a concern, can't you get a private npm repo? Yeah it costs.

Alternatively, you could host your own npm repo on your own server?

Comment: Yes, that is a good solution and I guess most organizations must be following this only. My problem is that this decision is not up to me to buy a private repo so I wanted a local based solution. But this is a correct approach to solve multi repo problem.